# MySQLi query skipping first 5 rows

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following MySqli query:

```
    $run = 0;
$result = $conn->query("SELECT title, author,i.isbn13, i.sku, quantity, weight, listed_price
from book
LEFT JOIN inventory i on book.isbn13 = i.isbn13
where quantity > 0 and i.isbn13 like '978%' limit $run, 5");
```

Which I then run through Amazon's API to return XML Data.  I then parse that to update my table with:

```
    $conn->query("update book set author = '" . addslashes($amazonResult['Author']) . "', title ='" . addslashes($amazonResult['Title']) . "',
         edition='" . addslashes($amazonResult['Edition']) . "',
         weight='" . $amazonResult['Weight'] . "', publisher='" . addslashes($amazonResult['Publisher']) . "', binding='" . $amazonResult['Binding'] . "',
         pub_date='" . $amazonResult['PublishDate'] . "', listed_price = '" .$amazonResult['ListPrice'] . "'
         where isbn13 = '" . $amazonResult['isbn'] . "'");
```

Update $run:

```
$run=$run+5;
```

and have it loop through again. Yet my output skips the first 5 rows in the table and returns the next 5. Also, after running about 20 or so records, it skips 5 again. The rows that it processes, it does correctly, which I verify by an echo of the query. When I use the query in Navicat, replace $run with 0, everything looks fine, the first 5 rows are returned.

Any idea what I did wrong or how I can fix this?  I have never encountered this in the past and use almost the same query for different reports.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a specific range of records, make sure to also add an `order by` clause. MySQL might change the order of rows between queries.

Another, maybe even more plausible cause, is that a query can sometimes fail. For instance, if one of the fields contains an invalid character, it might break your query, return false instead of a mysqli query result, and therefor fail to output anything.

You are using `addslashes` to escape strings, but that's not the proper way to do it. You can use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), or even better: use parameterized queries (prepared statements).

Comment: I did use order by isbn13 asc, and there was no difference.  What would you suggest instead of addslashes?  That is what works for my update command.

Comment: Thanks for the information about mysqli_real_escape_string, but that still does not solve my problem of the skipped records. That is what I am most concerned about.